# Rewriting folder won't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an app stored on my server in "SERVER_ROOT/app/1.0.1/index.php". The app is accessed by typing in "example.com/index.php" and I use a rewrite to achieve this.

The issue I am having is I want users to access "SERVER_ROOT/app/1.0.1/image/*" by typing "example.com/image/*" but none of my rewrites work when I edit the .htaccess file.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app/1.0.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^image/$ app/1.0.1/image/ [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Since the `/image/` directory doesn't actually exist, it'll get trapped by the first rule that routes everything to index.php. Assuming your htaccess file is in your document root, you need to add the rule above your routing rule and change it to this:

```
RewriteRule ^image/(.*)$ image/$1 [L]
```

If your htaccess file *isn't* in the document root, then you need to add this rule to the top of the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteRule ^image/(.*)$ /app/1.0.1/image/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It doesn't work if I place it at the top either. I placed it underneath the RewriteEngine On